# SYMPY doesn't work under Octave. Why it is not in a subdirectory of Python?

Tags: python, anaconda, octave

I use windows 10 and Octave 4.4. I wanted to run an Octave Script which needs the symbolic package of Octave. 
Therefore, I installed Anaconda\ miniconda (which was recommended somewhere for this) to have Python 3.7.1 and Sympy 1.3 installed. However, after adding the path fpr Python to the environment variables and the sympy Path I tried sympRef diagnose under Octave and got the message that Python runs but Sympy has not been found, asking if it is installed.
I wasted two days to find out why the symbolic package used in matlab and Octave 4.4 does not work although Python 3.7.1 (inside Anaconda) is installed and Anaconda (newest version) says that Sympy is also installed.
If I put the path of Python, Sympy and npmath in the environment variables - the sympy path being inside the directory of python, than it works, but if it is outside it doesn't work e.g. the following path as PATH in environment variables of WIndows:

Works: C:\Users\ThWillms\Miniconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.1-h33f27b4_4\Lib\sympy

does not work: 
C:\Users\ThWillms\Miniconda3\pkgs\sympy-1.3-py37_0\Lib\site-packages\sympy

the configuration being exactly the same but sympy copied from outside the python path inside the python Path (it is now two times on my hard disk).

1) Considering that all modules need to be imported in python why is the path to use them outside Python?? 
 Does the error occur because Octave only searches for the library path inside the python path or only Python does? Could this be changed in Anaconda? I don't want to have all libraries two times (considering the big number of modules and programs). There are already many postings in the internet concerning this problem but I could not find any solution in the internet how to make octave working with anaconda, its libraries etc.

I don't know if I have to tell this to the developpers or in this forum, but I don't know where to expose this problem, since it is not really a bug. So I ask it here to make the community know the problem, its (workaround) solution and to give them the possibility to improve anaconda.

2) Why does Anaconda needs to be installed under C:\users... etc. like old DOS Programs. Why are spaces a problem if 99 % of all programs have no problem with this? Shouldn't it be inside the directory C:\Programme or adequate?

3) Why does Anaconda not display all present versions of the programs and libraries in the navigator and not give the possibility to uninstall old versions of the libraries or programs there? This would be important in view of the size of the program and the big number of components. Better would be to delete all versions of a certain component and reinstall the newest one than accumulating all versions on the disk. Will this come in a future edition?

Comment: I'm really confused what the problem is here, and you didn't include any error messages, or code, just that it doesn't work. Do you expect Python packages to directly work in Octave?

Comment: No, off course I cannot access a module of python by Octave, if this is what you mean. I expect that python - which works if not installed with anaconda - can access the module sympy if installed, but in case of anaconda it cannot if I use Octave or Matlab to acces Python - as explained above.

Comment: So you want to start Python from within Matlab or Octave? Why do you want to do that? Your question is really unclear to me. Although I get that it can be frustrating to spend a lot of time trying to fix something, can you try to eliminate the parts of the text that don't focus specifically on what your main question is?

Comment: Ok, right is I missed an important point: I wanted to run the package symbolic of Octave necessary for symbolic calculations for a matlab script that I want to run. Symbolic needs Python and Sympy. Python - although installed by Anaconda or mini-conda - is found by Octave and works. Anaconda also says Sympy is working but when I started the script Sympy was never found by Octave - even not when giving the path of Sympy (outside od the Python directory) in the environment variables. Only when I copied it inside Python. But this is of course not as it should be...

Comment: OK, that makes a little more sense. Can you please [edit] your question and simplify/clarify?

Comment: I upvoted because I think this is an interesting issue. However, points (2) and (3) are no more than rants and should be deleted. Yes, they have question marks, but they are not actual questions that anyone here can (or should) answer.